Remove a specific colour shading from cells
I have a large word document with many tables. Each table has the same specific shading colour that I want removed (which haooens to be in the top row). There are other cells that have other shading which I want to ensure they remain as is. Is anyone able to provide a macros that can run through all tables in the document and remove the colour RGB 46, 116, 181?
I have tried a number of macros that I've found online but nothing has worked for me.
